Energy, and work applied by external/ non-conservative force
I have two doubts. One regarding the equation of work and energy relationship. The first doubt is the statement of the realtionship itself. In some arguments, they mention that
$$ E_{k1}+E_{p1}+W_{nc}=E_{k2}+E_{p2}$$ represent the change in the mechanical energy done by the work of a non-conservative force. They do not make explicit if it is done by a force considered as an internal or external force. In other arguments, it is just the work done by an external force to the system. Which is the accepted way and isn't there a way of unifying the perspectives? If I lift an object $h$ meters from the ground, I have made a non conservative force to it, thus, increasing its potential energy. When systems come into account, I can say that my system is exclusively the object I am lifting. In that case, I can not say there is potential energy and both my force and the gravitational force are external forces to the system. All I can say is that the net work done is zero.
My other doubt is that, sometimes, when systems are taken into account when dealing with energy and work, some people adopting the perspective that the term $W_{nc}$ in the previous equation is the work done by an external force to the system, do not consider as work something that clearly is doing work regardless of the system's perspective. In the example of lifting an object, if I consider the system to be object-earth, they say gravity is no longer doing work, but clearly the force $F_g=-mgh$ will excert a force throughout the distance covered, so by definition will do work.
Examples of videos that makes this point are this one and this other.

Please note that in this context a non-conservative force is any force that is not the gradient of a field, so for example if you kick the object in question the force you apply to it would be included here a non-conservative force.


Which is the accepted way and isn't there a way of unifying the perspectives?

The first way is usually the first one encountered, typically when studying basic mechanics. The second way you mention actually has its roots in thermodynamics where the first law of thermo can be written $$\Delta U = Q+W$$ where $U$ is the internal energy including all forms of energy, $Q$ is heat transferred to the system, and $W$ is work. For $Q=0$ and with $U=E_k+E_p$ we can write this in the form you mention as $$(E_{k2}+E_{p2})-(E_{k1}+E_{p1})=W$$$$E_{k1}+E_{p1} + W = E_{k2}+E_{p2}$$
In this view work is the transfer of energy to a system by any means other than heat. So, no distinction is made between conservative and non-conservative forces, but internal interactions cannot possibly do work. So $W$ is external work.
My personal preference is the second way, but certainly both ways are accepted so you should understand which approach your teacher or textbook author uses and use that approach in that class or in studying that textbook.

If I lift an object h meters from the ground, I have made a non conservative force to it, thus, increasing its potential energy. When systems come into account, I can say that my system is exclusively the object I am lifting. In that case, I can not say there is potential energy and both my force and the gravitational force are external forces to the system. All I can say is that the net work done is zero.

The total work is only zero if the KE is unchanged. Certainly a change of KE can happen when lifting an object using an external force.

In the example of lifting an object, if I consider the system to be object-earth, they say gravity is no longer doing work, but clearly the force $F_g=−mgh$ will excert a force throughout the distance covered, so by definition will do work.

Indeed, in my preferred approach, for this system gravity is an internal force so it cannot do any work. Gravity does not transfer energy in or out of this system. All it does is change energy from one form to another within the system. For example, it can change some of the system's kinetic energy into potential energy, but it does not change the total energy.
When you take such an approach, generally you do not analyze internal forces. A system is treated as a black box and nothing inside the system is analyzed. This is the approach that I take.
So, if I am interested in the gravitational force and any work that it does, then I would not choose a system where it is an internal force. Forces and transfers of energy that are of interest should always be placed on the boundary of the system.
For example, if I were interested in the work done by gravity then I would use the object as the system. Then gravity is an external force and can transfer energy in out of the system, thus doing work. The work done by gravity could then be related to the change in the internal energy (including KE) of the object plus any work done by other forces acting on the object.

Thank you for your response. Shouldn't there be an agnostic approach regarding the systems? It seems not completely consistent to have such conflicting perspectives in which only by system election one thing I have already defined as being work can no longer be considered as such.

@Curiousstudent that is a matter of opinion. My opinion is that the flexibility to be able to set what things you are interested in and what you are not interested in by judiciously choosing the system is a very useful tool that I would not want to get rid of
